# Homotopy classes of homeomorphism vs. Homotopy classes of a biholomorphism

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory

This is a more detailed question about my first question [Representation theory and topology of Teichmüller space](https://mathoverflow.net/q/460367/516181), I asked there how to understand:

> $$T_{g}\hookrightarrow Hom(\pi_{1}({S}),PSL_{2}(\mathbb{R}))/PSL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$$

below is the definition of Teichmüller space I used.

> Suppose S is a topological surface of genus $g\geq 2$. A marked Riemann surface $(X, f)$ is a Riemann surface X together with a homemorphism $f:S\rightarrow X$. Two marked surfaces $ (X,f)\sim (Y,g)$ are equivalent if $gf^{-1}: X\rightarrow Y$ is isotopic to an isomorphism(biholomorphism). The Teichmüller space $T_g$ is given by:

> $$T_g=\{(X,f)\}/\sim$$

Thanks to @Andy Putman, where he gave some hints in the comments. Let me summarize here, below S is always a hyperbolic Riemann surface of genus at least 2:

> The group of biholomorphisms of **D** is $PSL_{2}(\mathcal{ℝ})$. This shows that $\cong /\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $PSL_{2}(\mathcal{ℝ})$. The marking on  lets you identify $\pi_{1}()$ with $\Gamma$(up to conj due to basepts), so we get a point in your rep space. Reversing this process gives you the inverse map from the rep space to Teichmuller space.

> About how markings of S identify $\pi_{1}()$ with $\Gamma$(up to conj due to basepts). If  and ′ are two surfaces of genus $\geq 1$, then they're both $(\pi,1)$'s for their fundamental group, so **the set of homotopy classes of homeomorphisms from  to ′ is the same as the set of conjugacy classes of isomorphisms between their fundamental groups**. Thus a marking of a surface of genus at least 1 is the same as an identification of its fundamental group with that of your fixed reference surface (up to conjugacy)

If I don't understand wrongly, he used the property of $K(G,1)$ here, namely Proposition 1B.9 in Hatcher's book "Algebraic topology".

> Let X be a connected CW-complexes, and Y be a K(G,1). Then any homomorphism $\pi_{1}(X,x_{0})\rightarrow \pi_{1}(Y,y_{0}) $ is induced by a map $(X,x_{0})\rightarrow (Y,y_{0})$, which is unique up to homotopy fixing $x_{0}$

What I want to show is the marking, which is the **homotopy classes of biholomorphism of hyperbolic Riemann Surfaces**, identify with $Hom(\pi_{1}({S}),PSL_{2}(\mathbb{R}))/PSL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. So my questions are:

1. **Are homotopy classes of **homeomorphism** between hyperbolic Riemann Surfaces the same thing as homotopy classes of **biholomorphsim** between hyperbolic Riemann Surfaces?**
2. I want to prove if (X, f)~(Y, g), then their corresponding representations are conjugate in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$. The representation corresponding to (X, f) is induced from  f by:

$$\pi_{1}(S)\stackrel{f_{*}}\rightarrow \pi_{1}(X)\cong \Gamma_{X}\subset Aut(D)$$

**If the answer to question 1 is right, how can I show "if (X, f)~(Y, g), then their corresponding representations are conjugate in $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$" using "the set of homotopy classes of homeomorphisms from  to ′ is the same as the set of conjugacy classes of isomorphisms between their fundamental groups"?**

In other words, we have known that:

$$\pi_{1}(S)\stackrel{f_{*}}\rightarrow \pi_{1}(X)\cong \Gamma_{X}\subset Aut(D)$$
and:

$$\pi_{1}(S)\stackrel{g_{*}}\rightarrow \pi_{1}(Y)\cong \Gamma_{Y}\subset Aut(D)$$

are two representations of $\pi_{1}(S)$ on **D**, then the set $Hom(\pi_{1}({S}),PSL_{2}(\mathbb{R}))/PSL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ is bijective to the set of all the group isomorphism:

$$h:\pi_{1}(X)\rightarrow \pi_{1}(Y)$$

up to conjugacy?

P.S: Maybe the second question is easy to answer because right now I'm stuck in these definitions and maybe I ignore something obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, certainly not.  Biholomorphic maps are very rare and very rigid.  Generically, given Riemann surfaces $X$ and $Y$, there will be *no* biholomorphic maps between them.
2. Yes.  You will want to read up on the "developing map" derived from a hyperbolic structure, and its associated "holonomy representation".  These are part of Thurston's more general notion of $(G, X)$ structures.  You can find a discussion of the history and many references in this [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332012/history-of-the-notion-of-g-x-structure).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question again! As to the first question I asked, your answer actually tells me that Prop 1B.9 in Hatcher's book is not enough right? According to your answer of my second question, even in this case, I must asked for Thurston's (G,X) structures to give a detailed proof...After all, thank you for providing another aspect to view this problem!